# Converting htmlwidget to ggplot object in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly, htmlwidgets

I'm wondering if it's possible to convert a `plotly` object to a `ggplot2` object in `R`? I have a plot object of class `plotly htmlwidget`.

I've tried the `as.ggplot()` function from the `ggplotify` package, but get the following error

> Error in UseMethod("as.grob") : 
>     no applicable method for 'as.grob' applied to an object of class "c('plotly', 'htmlwidget')"

Is anyone aware of any alternative methods?

Background: I'm trying to arrange multiple `Sankey diagrams` into a single plot (e.g., using `grid.arrange()`). There's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089207/how-to-arrange-html-widget-plots-in-a-grid-for-export-as-pdf) that suggests using Rshiny, but I'm wondering if it'd be possible to convert to a static ggplot object instead.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
  library(plotly)
  library(ggplotify)
  p <- plot_ly(
    type = "sankey",
    orientation = "h",
    width = 600,
    height = 400,

    node = list(
      label = c(c('A','B'), c('A','B')),
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = list(
        color = "black",
        width = 0.5
      )
    ),

    link = list(
      source = c(0,1,0,1),
      target = c(2,2,3,3),
      value =  c(1,2,3,4)
    )
  )
  class(p)
  as.ggplot(p)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to convert to ggplot2 to arrange your plotly objects. Instead, the plotly package has a very nice and customizable subplot() function for you to use. Like:

```
p <- subplot(p1, p2, p3, p4, nrows = 2)
```

The function can arrange the plots in any fashion you like, I suggest you check out the gallery online for ideas:

https://plot.ly/r/subplot-charts/

But to answer your question, no, there is no way to convert a plotly object to a ggplot2 one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried what you suggested with the example I provided (changing the values slightly for `p2`) and the plots display on top of each other, not in separate rows: https://plot.ly/~tgwilliams/11/#/

any thoughts why this might be?

Comment: OK I found out how to arrange multiple Sankey diagrams using the `subplot()` function in plotly. When defining the plot (`p` in this example), you need to add an additional `domain` key, e.g. `domain = list(x=c(0,0.45), y=c(0,1))`, which specifies the relative position of the plot in the plot window.

Comment: That's strange. I wonder why it didn't make a grid like it normally does. In any case, I'm glad you found a workable solution.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the other answer has already satisfied your use case, but for completeness, here is a way to construct your sankey in ggplot, convert it to plotly for interactivity, and then be able to convert that back into ggplot (which was in the original question) using [notly](https://github.com/gdmcdonald/notly).

```r
# install.packages("remotes")
# remotes::install_github("davidsjoberg/ggsankey")
library(ggsankey)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
# remotes::install_github("gdmcdonald/notly")
library(notly)
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars %>%
  make_long(cyl, vs, am, gear, carb)

sankey <- 
  ggplot(data = df, 
       mapping = aes(x = x, 
                     next_x = next_x, 
                     node = node, 
                     next_node = next_node,
                     fill = factor(node))) +
  geom_sankey() +
  theme_sankey(base_size = 16) 

plotly_sankey <- ggplotly(sankey)

plotly_sankey

ggplot_sankey <- notly(plotly_sankey)

ggplot_sankey
```